# Brew won't upgrade on Mojave

Tags: homebrew, macos-mojave

I have installed:

- Xcode 10
- Command Line Tools (macOS 10.14) for Xcode 10 Beta and Beta 2
- macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg using this:

  ```
  sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
  ```

I have also opened Xcode 10 and waited for it to install components.

Brew still gives me the error:

```
Error: The Command Line Tools header package must be installed on Mojave.
The installer is located at:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

Here is brew config

```
$ brew config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.6.12
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 0aab25bdb3bfa96d8eb14a38001ff6a24587bcdd
Last commit: 8 hours ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: bde1292d5f98949e3f566b78c05e08bd30914afe
Core tap last commit: 4 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
CPU: quad-core 64-bit broadwell
Homebrew Ruby: 2.3.7 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
Clang: 10.0 build 1000
Git: 2.17.1 => /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.54.0 => /usr/bin/curl
Java: N/A
macOS: 10.14-x86_64
CLT: 10.0.0.0.1.1527767617
CLT headers: N/A
Xcode: 10.0 => /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
XQuartz: 2.7.11 => /opt/X11
```

What should I do next to get Brew to work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51274905/brew-install-on-mojave/51277659?noredirect=1#comment89551330_51277659 Check my answer here, if you have same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got an update through Software Update for Command Line Tools for Xcode 10 Beta 3.

I installed that and re-installed SDK headers and it now works.

It's weird that it doesn't show up in https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Answer (score 3):

Same situation. Also just got an update through Software Update for Command Line Tools for Xcode 10 Beta 3.

I installed that and re-installed updated SDK headers and `brew config` now shows `CLT headers`, yeah!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, after a restart the file appeared on /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg

I opened and installed it. Now brew is working again.

Comment: I've installed these headers twice, and rebooted but it still acts as if they aren't there.
Any ideas?

Comment: Update Command Line Tools from Mac's Settings -> updates (Mojave moves system updates from App Store to Settings) then install headers again from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg. Now it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Movaje 10.14.6 - This is what I did:

1. Uninstall Xcode
2. Install Xcode ([11.2.1](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11.2.1/Xcode_11.2.1.xip))
3. run `xcode-select --install`
4. run `sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /`