# Where are the C headers in MacOS Mojave?

Tags: c, xcode, macos, header-files, macos-mojave

It seems that Apple keeps on moving their tools around and the old solution of installing the command line tools are with using `xcode-select --install` doesn't work.

In Mojave, `xcode-select` doesn't install anything anymore (the GUI always fails to find the package) and the command line tools don't install itself in `/usr/` or `/usr/local`.

Comment: In my installation, `/usr/include` seems to have all the C header files I would expect and `Xcode-select --install` tells me everything is already installed.

Comment: Which version of Xcode do you have?

Comment: Xcode 10.1, Mojave 10.14.1.

Comment: Have you actually run Xcode? The first time it opens, it tells you it is going to install "additional components". I assume this is where it sets up `/usr/include`

Comment: I have been using Xcode for a very long time, Xcode itself works, but I need the location of headers for running clang from brew (or more precisely compiling with clangtooling).

Comment: I guess I must be missing something else...

Comment: `xcrun --show-sdk-path` will tell you where the SDK is but you should also have the C SDK in the usual Unix locations.

Comment: OK, thanks I will have a look again tonight.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52904079/1187415.

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51274905/brew-install-on-mojave.

Comment: Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337940/why-is-usr-include-missing-i-have-xcode-and-command-line-tools-installed-moja .

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`xcode-select --install` did work for me in Mojave. Maybe you can try installing XCode from Mac App Store, and then install developer tools?

Regarding header locations, I have Apples headers in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`:

```
$ sudo find /Library -name stdio.h 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/stdio.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/stdio.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/sys/stdio.h
```

And if you install gcc via brew, it will add headers in `/usr/local/`:

```
$ sudo find /usr -name stdio.h 
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/tr1/stdio.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/lib/gcc/8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0/8.2.0/include/ssp/stdio.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/lib/gcc/8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0/8.2.0/include-fixed/stdio.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.1.0/include/c++/8.1.0/tr1/stdio.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.1.0/lib/gcc/8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0/8.1.0/include/ssp/stdio.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.1.0/lib/gcc/8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0/8.1.0/include-fixed/stdio.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.3.0_1/include/c++/7.3.0/tr1/stdio.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.3.0_1/lib/gcc/7/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0/7.3.0/include/ssp/stdio.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@7/7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/tr1/stdio.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@7/7.3.0/lib/gcc/7/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0/7.3.0/include/ssp/stdio.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@7/7.3.0/lib/gcc/7/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0/7.3.0/include-fixed/stdio.h
/usr/local/include/c++/8.2.0/tr1/stdio.h
/usr/local/lib/gcc/8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0/8.2.0/include/ssp/stdio.h
/usr/local/lib/gcc/8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0/8.2.0/include-fixed/stdio.h
```

(Those are not Apple's headers, but GCC / GLIBC).

Using dtruss I can see that Apple clang uses the one in `CommandLineTools/SDKs`:

```
$ sudo dtruss -f sudo -u $USER clang test.c -o test 2>&1
3781/0x51d8:  pread(0x3, "#include <stdio.h>\n\nint main(void)\n{\n  printf(\"Hello, world\\n\");\n  return 0;\n}\n\0", 0x4F, 0x0)              = 79 0
3781/0x51d8:  __pthread_sigmask(0x3, 0x7FFEE3A7E768, 0x7FFEE3A7E76C)            = 0 0
3781/0x51d8:  close(0x3)                = 0 0
3781/0x51d8:  __pthread_sigmask(0x3, 0x7FFEE3A7E76C, 0x0)               = 0 0
3781/0x51d8:  open("/usr/local/include/stdio.h\0", 0x1000000, 0x1A)             = -1 Err#2
3781/0x51d8:  open("/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stdio.h\0", 0x1000000, 0x48)               = -1 Err#2
3781/0x51d8:  open("/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/stdio.h\0", 0x1000000, 0x37)                = -1 Err#2
3781/0x51d8:  open("/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h\0", 0x1000000, 0x47)                = 3 0
```

Comment: I probably need to reinstall it at some point... But using the CommandLineTools path seems to work (until the next failure, that's in libtooling).

Answer (score 8):

Xcode now supports multiple SDKs and multiple installations of Xcode. The SDKs are inside Xcode.app, and Xcode.app is installed by default in Applications but may be elsewhere.

`xcrun --show-sdk-path` will show a default SDK path, but there may be others. For example, one possible path is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk`. From there, `usr/include` holds common public headers such as the standard C headers, and various Apple headers are in frameworks under `System`.

In `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms`, you will likely find folders for other platforms, such as `iPhoneOS.platform` and `AppleTVOS.platform`. Within those, `Developer/SDKs` leads to SDKs for those platforms.

Answer (score 4):

Per the following article:
https://silvae86.github.io/sysadmin/mac/osx/mojave/beta/libxml2/2018/07/05/fixing-missing-headers-for-homebrew-in-mac-osx-mojave/

This will install the headers:

open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg

Comment: This file no longer exists.