# Upgrading from Postgres 10 to 11 with Postgis

Tags: xcode, postgresql, clang, homebrew, postgis

I've recently had to upgrade from Postgres version from 10 to 11 with `homebrew` on my macOS Mojave and because of the need to use Postgis it looks not so trivial to follow the standard way of using `brew postgresql-upgrade-database` after upgrading Postgres version.

I've found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/smellman/2e51b1cf449c499ad5deec454a16a7bc) that looks pretty much as a probable solution for my problem. When I try to run `make` on the `postgis-2.5.1` it throws an error that seems like it confuses the `Command Line Tools` with the `Xcode` path, which I currently don't have installed.

Below I paste the sequence of commands I've tried so far:

```
❯ xcrun --show-sdk-path
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk

❯ ./configure --with-pgconfig=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.6_1/bin/pg_config --with-xml2config=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.9_2/bin/xml2-config --with-projdir=/usr/local/Cellar/proj/5.2.0 --with-jsondir=/usr/local/Cellar/json-c/0.13.1 --with-pcredir=/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.4

❯ make
/usr/local/bin/perl utils/svn_repo_revision.pl
Can't fetch local revision (neither .svn nor .git found)
Not updating existing rev file at 17027
for s in liblwgeom libpgcommon postgis regress raster topology loader utils doc extensions; do \
                echo "---- Making all in ${s}"; \
                /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -C ${s} all || exit 1; \
        done;
---- Making all in liblwgeom
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
---- Making all in libpgcommon
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
---- Making all in postgis
clang -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -O2  -I../liblwgeom -g -O2 -I../libpgcommon  -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.1_1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/proj/5.2.0/include  -I/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.9_2/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/sfcgal/1.3.6/include -DHAVE_SFCGAL -I/usr/local/Cellar/json-c/0.13.1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.42/include  -fPIC -I/usr/local/Cellar/sfcgal/1.3.6/include -DHAVE_SFCGAL -I. -I./ -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.6_1/include/server -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.6_1/include/internal -I/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/63.1/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o postgis_module.o postgis_module.c
clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk' [-Wmissing-sysroot]
In file included from postgis_module.c:26:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.6_1/include/server/postgres.h:47:
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.6_1/include/server/c.h:81:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [postgis_module.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Even if I explicitly set the `sysroot` path on `./configure` or set `CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT` before issuing `make` it won't work.

```
❯ ./configure --with-sysroot=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/ --with-pgconfig=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.6_1/bin/pg_config --with-xml2config=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.9_2/bin/xml2-config --with-projdir=/usr/local/Cellar/proj/5.2.0 --with-jsondir=/usr/local/Cellar/json-c/0.13.1 --with-pcredir=/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.4

❯ CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk make
/usr/local/bin/perl utils/svn_repo_revision.pl
Can't fetch local revision (neither .svn nor .git found)
Not updating existing rev file at 17027
for s in liblwgeom libpgcommon postgis regress raster topology loader utils doc extensions; do \
                echo "---- Making all in ${s}"; \
                /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -C ${s} all || exit 1; \
        done;
---- Making all in liblwgeom
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
---- Making all in libpgcommon
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
---- Making all in postgis
clang -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -O2  -I../liblwgeom -g -O2 -I../libpgcommon  -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.1_1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/proj/5.2.0/include  -I/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.9_2/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/sfcgal/1.3.6/include -DHAVE_SFCGAL -I/usr/local/Cellar/json-c/0.13.1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.42/include  -fPIC -I/usr/local/Cellar/sfcgal/1.3.6/include -DHAVE_SFCGAL -I. -I./ -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.6_1/include/server -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.6_1/include/internal -I/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/63.1/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o postgis_module.o postgis_module.c
clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk' [-Wmissing-sysroot]
In file included from postgis_module.c:26:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.6_1/include/server/postgres.h:47:
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.6_1/include/server/c.h:81:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [postgis_module.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

For the record, I've already installed `macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg` I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53169970/where-are-the-c-headers-in-macos-mojave) and [here](https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/338) that it might be required.

I'd really appreciate any clues or tips on what I might be doing wrong or any other approaches that could fix the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get an answer on this outside of StackOverflow by chance? I'm encountering the same problems after going through the same steps.

Comment: @mattdeboard just reported below. hopefully that will work for you!

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of struggle, I have ended up by dumping the old databases altogether with:

```
pg_dumpall > /tmp/my_databases.sql
```

and then installed a fresh Postgres and restored all data back on the new version using:

```
psql -f /tmp/my_databases.sql
```

I hope it helps others in the future.