# Missing header files on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, gcc

I am having issues with header files on macOS Catalina. I get command-line tool errors like the following :

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:443:29: error: parameter name omitted
 int     getiopolicy_np(int, int) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_2_0);
                             ^~~
```

and gcc errors

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@8/8.3.0/lib/gcc/8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.3.0/include-fixed/math.h:535:15: error: storage class specified for parameter 'nextafte'
 extern double nextafter(double, double);
```

---

I dig into header files and gcc on macOS Catalina use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53169970/where-are-the-c-headers-in-macos-mojave) answer as a reference point. The answer states

> ```
> Regarding header locations, I have Apples headers in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/:
>
> $ sudo find /Library -name stdio.h 
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/stdio.h
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/stdio.h
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.
> ```

When I run the same command, the header locations are slightly different:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/stdio.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/sys/stdio.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/sys/stdio.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/stdio.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/sys/stdio.h
```

As can be seen the SDKs are now split into MACOSX10.14 and 10.15 unlinke before. Another difference is with the header files. According the the answer in reference,

> ```
> if you install gcc via brew, it will add headers in /usr/local/:
>
> $ sudo find /usr -name stdio.h 
> /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/tr1/stdio.h
> /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/lib/gcc/8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0/8.2.0/include/ssp/stdio.h
> /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/lib/gcc/8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0/8.2.0/include-fixed/stdio.h
> /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.1.0/include/c++/8.1.0/tr1/stdio.h
> /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.1.0/lib/gcc/8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0/8.1.0/include/ssp/stdio.h
> /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.1.0/lib/gcc/8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0/8.1.0/include-fixed/stdio.h
> /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.3.0_1/include/c++/7.3.0/tr1/stdio.h
> /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.3.0_1/lib/gcc/7/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0/7.3.0/include/ssp/stdio.h
> /usr/local/Cellar/gcc@7/7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/tr1/stdio.h
> /usr/local/Cellar/gcc@7/7.3.0/lib/gcc/7/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0/7.3.0/include/ssp/stdio.h
> /usr/local/Cellar/gcc@7/7.3.0/lib/gcc/7/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0/7.3.0/include-fixed/stdio.h
> /usr/local/include/c++/8.2.0/tr1/stdio.h
> /usr/local/lib/gcc/8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0/8.2.0/include/ssp/stdio.h
> /usr/local/lib/gcc/8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0/8.2.0/include-fixed/stdio.h
> ```

However, when I run the above command I get:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@8/8.3.0/include/c++/8.3.0/tr1/stdio.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@8/8.3.0/lib/gcc/8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.3.0/include/ssp/stdio.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@8/8.3.0/lib/gcc/8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.3.0/include-fixed/stdio.h
```

Where are the other header files? What should these commands return in macOS Catalina?

Comment: I have the same issue.  In OSX 10.14., all the headers in /Include could be installed from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg but the same pkg file is not there under 10.15.

Comment: Any suggestions on what can be done? Could you up-vote/share if you have the same issue, maybe others who have solved this issue will see the question?

Answer (score 0):

Referring you to this solution. I have answered there yesterday. It will be useful if you usually write C/C++ codes and looking for C/C++ headers or the previous header files in `/usr/include`. But in Catalina, there is no `/usr/include` folder from this update and you may not be able to create `/usr/include` folder as the system mounts  Read-Only mode.

[Can't compile a C program on a Mac after upgrading to Catalina 10.15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278260/cant-compile-a-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrading-to-catalina-10-15/58349403#58349403)

You may try this solution.