# intel C++ cannot open "wchar.h" on mac osx

Tags: c++, macos, macos-mojave, icc

System OSX 10.14.6, macbook pro

Trying to compile this simple C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    sdt::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Have gcc 9 installed via homebrew, as well as XCode command line tools.

Both of the following work

```sh
c++ main.cpp
g++-9 main.cpp
```

Trying out the latest Intel Parallel Studio, the following fails:

```sh
> icpc main.cpp 
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/iosfwd(90),
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/ios(215),
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream(38),
                 from main.cpp(1):
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h(119): catastrophic error: cannot open source file "wchar.h"
  #include_next <wchar.h>
                         ^

compilation aborted for main.cpp (code 4)
```

Can someone tell me what I am missing here?

---

**EDIT RESPONSE TO COMMENT ABOUT find**

searching from `/` for `wchar.h` yields many wchar.h files, including the one from the error:

```
./usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_3/include/c++/9.2.0/tr1/wchar.h
./Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h
./Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h
./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h
./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h
./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchOS.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h
./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h
./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk/System/DriverKit/usr/include/wchar.h
./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h
./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h
./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h
./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h
./opt/intel/intelpython3/include/c++/v1/support/solaris/wchar.h
./opt/intel/intelpython3/include/c++/v1/wchar.h
./opt/intel/intelpython3/pkgs/libcxx-4.0.1-hcfea43d_1/include/c++/v1/support/solaris/wchar.h
./opt/intel/intelpython3/pkgs/libcxx-4.0.1-hcfea43d_1/include/c++/v1/wchar.h
./dev/fd/3/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h
./dev/fd/3/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h
./dev/fd/3/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchOS.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h
./dev/fd/3/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h
./dev/fd/3/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk/System/DriverKit/usr/include/wchar.h
./dev/fd/3/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h
./dev/fd/3/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h
./dev/fd/3/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h
./dev/fd/3/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h
./dev/fd/3/opt/intel/intelpython3/include/c++/v1/support/solaris/wchar.h
./dev/fd/3/opt/intel/intelpython3/include/c++/v1/wchar.h
./dev/fd/3/opt/intel/intelpython3/pkgs/libcxx-4.0.1-hcfea43d_1/include/c++/v1/support/solaris/wchar.h
./dev/fd/3/opt/intel/intelpython3/pkgs/libcxx-4.0.1-hcfea43d_1/include/c++/v1/wchar.h
```

Comment: From what I red the location of the headers change between different releases. If I read [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53169970/where-are-the-c-headers-in-macos-mojave) correctly, they can be found in a different path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/...), if I were you I would try to locate the header files via 'find' or check the proposed path and then adjust the root include path accordingly.

Comment: @mutableVoid see the edit to the answer.  The header file in the error seems to exist.  I saw some answers around but seems like there is something I'm missing regarding configuring just the intel compiler

Comment: The question is, which one do you want to use? You need to specify that with your compile command.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, this solved the problem:

```
icpc main.cpp -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

Intel C++ compiler on macOS is highly sensitive to the version of Xcode being used. For example, I receive the same errors as above when using icpc 2020 Initial Release and Xcode 11.3.1, but the code compiles and executes just fine with "icpc main.cpp" when using Xcode 11.2.1.

This has been the situation with Intel C++ compilers for some time on macOS... check your Xcode version and try again.